# Use VBA to open multiple files that run VBA on open at the same tjme

Tags: excel, vba

I have one excel file that opens other excel files using VBA. These other excel files all run code on open — currently when the main file opens a file, it waits for the on open code to run in the file it just opened, and then opens the next file. I would like it to just open the files then move on to opening the next file without waiting for the on open code to finish —  (I plan on limiting the number of files it has open at a time using process IDs) — any tips?

Comment: does the sub that runs when the workbook is opened start like "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" or "Sub Auto_Open()"? Also, do you want a macro to run automatically when you open it programmatically?

Comment: I would recommend to write a VB script instead of using VBA...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888282/getting-a-xlsm-file-to-not-execute-code-when-being-opened-with-vba

Comment: @w-hit private sub workbook_open() and I want the macro to run programmatically.  —

Comment: @irene G yes it would be great if I could use VB but unfortunately I need a SAP VBA specific API

Comment: @simple solution — thanks for the help— but I want the code to run :/

Answer (score 0):

First you disable the run of macros, open the workbooks as you need them and then you reenable the run of macros. (as proposed here: [Getting a .xlsm file to not execute code when being opened with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888282/getting-a-xlsm-file-to-not-execute-code-when-being-opened-with-vba))

```
Private Sub OpenWorkBookMacroDisabled(wbPath As String)
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Workbooks.Open (wbPath)
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
    'or
    'Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
End Sub
```

**But actually this does not solve your problem.** To run the macros it would be necessary to reopen the workbooks which then would again autostart the individual macros.

**Workaround 1**
A possible solution is mentioned here: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/47477-enabling-macros-without-re-opening-worksheet:

> **CREATE AN ENABLE/DISABLE VALIDATION CELL**
>   *The only work around if it was a problem could be something like a validation cell on your home / front page that said " enabled" / "disabled".
>
>   Then when opening the workbook always enable the macro's, then on workbook open auto set this to disabled.
>
>   then you would have all macros look at this ref and if disabled not run, and you would need to dial up enabled to allow any macro to run.
>
>   May not be what you want but a thought.*

**Workaround 2**
Another workaround could be:
(1) Open the workbook(s) with the code mentioned above.
(2) Change `Sub Workbook_Open` to `Sub Workbook_Open_OLD` programmatically
(3) Save the workbook(s)
(4) Change `AutomationSecurity` to the desired level
(5) reopen your workbook(s)
Quite a lot of work!
For details see: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

**Workaround 3**
A variation to the enable/disable validation cell is the use of a central property
e.g. Application.Username

```
**This Macro calls the 'other excel files':**  
Sub Main0()
    'TEST 1:
    'Open workbook and DON'T run macros
    'Call "YourCode" manually

    Application.UserName = "NoMacroRun"
    Debug.Print "Test 1:"
    Debug.Print Application.UserName
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\macro_010.xlsb"
    Debug.Print "Open finished"
    Debug.Print "Call YourCode"
     Run "macro_010.xlsb!YourCode"
    Workbooks("macro_010.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Debug.Print "Test 1: FINISHED successfully"
    Debug.Print ""


    'TEST 2:
    'Open workbook and run macros

    Application.UserName = "SomeThingElse"
    Debug.Print "Test 2:"
    Debug.Print Application.UserName
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\macro_010.xlsb"
    Debug.Print "Test 2: FINISHED successfully"
    Debug.Print ""
    Workbooks("macro_010.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Debug.Print ""
End Sub
```

**The other files look like:**
In 'the other files' you seperate "YourCode" from "Workbook_Open" and make it callable from the outside:

```
'doubleclick "ThisWorkbook" in the IDE and insert this code there
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Application.UserName <> "NoMacroRun" Then
        Debug.Print "---> " & ThisWorkbook.Name & ": Workbook_Open is part of ThisWorkbook in the IDE"

        'your code
        Call YourCode

    End If
End Sub
```

This code you insert into a module:

```
'doubleclick "module" in the IDE and insert this code there
'OR click in the menu --> Insert --> Module
Sub YourCode()
        Debug.Print "---> " & ThisWorkbook.Name & ": ""Sub YourCode"" is part of a module in the IDE!"
End Sub
```

And finally, the **Immediate Window** proves that it works as intended:

```
Test 1:
NoMacroRun
Open finished
Call YourCode
---> macro_010.xlsb: "Sub YourCode" is part of a module in the IDE!
Test 1: finished successfully

Test 2:
SomeThingElse
---> macro_010.xlsb: Workbook_Open is part of ThisWorkbook in the IDE
---> macro_010.xlsb: "Sub YourCode" is part of a module in the IDE!
Test 2: finished successfully
```

Q.E.D. ;-)

[image]